# perl script to verify values present in xml files

Tags: xml, perl, file, for-loop

There are more than 50 xml files for me to check the value of

```
<Number>50<Number> present in the xml file.
```

The standard format of all xml files are the same. Sample below:

```
<Employee>
    <EmployeeId>1</ EmployeeId >
    <DeptId>E</DeptId>
    <InternId>94</internId>
     <Number>10<Number>
```

1.I need to check the value of Number in all the 50 xml files.
2. Need to get the input  from the user itself . e.g.: `my $input = <STDIN>;`
3.Based on the input received from the user have to check the value in all xml files and print the value and the filename.

Pl help. I am a beginner in Perl.

I used :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; 
use warnings; 
sub main
{
 my $input = <STDIN>;
 print "You entered: $input";
}
main();
```

But do not know how to get to access the xml files after the getting the INPUT.
how to search all the files in a directory for a node  AND PRINT ITS VALUE.

Comment: For what kind of "check the value" do you need user input for? You can print the value and name of file without any user input.

Comment: For e.g.: <STDIN>  is <NUMBER>  from the user and the <NUMBER> is searched in all the xml files and the value of <NUMBER>10<NUMBER> i.e. 10 is printed and differs for all xml values. so 50values from 50 xml values has to be printed.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl  
@files = glob ("C: Perl/*.xml");
foreach $file (@files) {
open   (FILE, "$file");
while($line= <FILE> ){
print "$line" if $line =~ /Number/;
}
close FILE; 
} This code returns empty result. Pl help

Comment: I'm guessing that your `glob` doesn't return what you think it does.  After the first semicolon above, add `print "files are: @files\n";` and see if you get what you expect.  Additionally, replace `open (FILE, "$file");` with `open (FILE, $file) || die "Can not open $file for reading ($!)";` and see if you get any errors from that.

Comment: When I changed and ran the code : The result is :Global symbol "$line" requires explicit package name at file.pl line 11.
Execution of file.pl aborted due to compilation errors. Do not know what is the problem. somewhere "if $line =~ /Number/" is a problem. Pl help .

Answer (score 0):

I would go with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir_to_search = "/path/to_xml/files/";

print "Please enter a search term for the 'Number' field:";
my $input = <STDIN>;
chomp $input;
$input = quotemeta $input;    #avoid regex injection

foreach my $file ( glob "$dir_to_search/*.xml" ) {
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
        'pretty_print'  => 'indented_a',
        'twig_handlers' => {
            'Number' => sub {
                if ( $_->text_only =~ m/^$input$/ ) {
                    print "$file contains ", $_->print,"\n";
                }
            }
        }
    );
    $twig->parsefile($file);
}
```